# Call a history back button after jquery fadeout

Tags: jquery-animate, jquery

I need to call `parent.history.back();` after a jquery function is called.
My code looks like this:

```
if((counteditems).length == 0) {
             $("li.res").fadeIn("slow");
             $('div.no-items').fadeIn("slow", "linear");
             $('div.no-items .close-it').click(function(){
                     $("div.no-items").fadeOut('slow',  function() {

                        parent.history.back();
                        return false;

                });

              });  
        }
```

There are some items counted and if their length is equal zero then `li.res` should be shown.
After that a `div.no-items` should fade in. In this `div.no-items` there is a close it button. When i click on it the `div.no-items` should fadeOut and after that the "back-button" of the browser should be fired.
Everything works like it should be but exept the fading out. It fades out and then fades in and fires the back button but the `div.no-items` remains.
Whats wrong with my code?

EDIT: I am using jquery BBQ

Comment: Add this to your javascript (above `$(document).ready()`) : `history.navigationMode = 'compatible';`

Comment: Is the page reloading and are you going back to a regular page, or are you going back to a page that is pushed into the history object with pushState ?

Comment: @adneo I am using jquery BBQ and my page ist is pushed in the history object with pushState. Any solution to this?